# Azure Search default database type

Tags: azure

I am new to Azure Search and I have just seen this tutorial https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/search-howto-dotnet-sdk/ on how to create/delete an index, upload and search for documents. However, I am wondering what type of database is behind the Azure Search functionality. In the given example I couldn't see it specified. Am I right if I assume it is implicitly DocumentDb?

At the same time, how could I specify the type of another database inside the code? How could I possibly use a Sql Server database? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, I am wondering what type of database is behind the Azure
>   Search functionality.

Azure Search is offered to you as a service. The team hasn't made the underlying storage mechanism public so it's not possible to know what kind of database are they using to store the data. However you interact with the service in form of JSON records. Each document in your index is sent/retrieved (and possibly saved) in form of JSON.

> At the same time, how could I specify the type of another database
>   inside the code? How could I possibly use a Sql Server database?

Short answer, you can't. Because it is a service, you can't specify the service to index any data source. However what you could do is ask search service to populate its database (read index) through multiple sources - SQL Databases, DocumentDB Collections and Blob Containers (currently in preview). This is achieved through something called `Data Sources` and `Indexers`. Once configured properly, Azure Search Service will constantly update the index data with the latest data in the specified data source.